# why self defining function reference keeps pointing to the old function

Tags: javascript

I find this example in "javascript design patterns" and confused with the behavior of following code

this code creates a self defining function:

```
var scareMe = function () {
   alert("Boo!");
   scareMe = function () {
     alert("Double boo!");
  };
};
```

now we are referencing  it to another variable

```
var prank = scareMe;
```

confusing part is when I called prank it should update scareMe and when i call it back it should alert "Double boo" isn't it?

but the result is

```
prank(); // "Boo!"
prank(); // "Boo!"
```

and if I check scareMe function indeed it has been redefined.

```
scareMe(); // Double boo!
```

prank is just a reference to scareMe than why there is a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`prank` points at the original function, not to `scareMe`.**

Look at this example:

```
var scareMe = 1;
var prank = scareMe;

scareMe = 2;
```

You don't expect that changing `scareMe` would change `prank`, right? It's exactly the same with functions.

```
var scareMe = function() { alert( 'Boo' ); };
var prank = scareMe;

scareMe = function() { alert( 'Double boo!' ); };
```

There is no difference between integers and functions in this regard—`prank` stays the same, even when `scareMe` changes. That `scareMe` is changed from inside another function does not change this fact.

The confusion might come from how objects are usually used. It's not as common to mutate the original function as you might change an object's properties.

```
var scareMe = { message: 'Boo' };
var prank = scareMe;

scareMe.message = 'Double boo!';

alert( prank.message );  // alerts 'Double boo!'
```

This is not what you're doing with functions in the original example. Changing a variable to point to a completely different function does not change the function reference in the other variable.

Comment: Objects are not different. You are simply doing a different thing, mutating an object is not the same as assigment of a variable. Furthermore, functions behave exactly like objects but are also callable. You could have mutated the function object just like you did with the plain object.

Comment: very nicely explained!! @Juhana

Answer (score 6):

`prank` is not a reference to `scareMe` (this is **impossible** in javascript), it's a reference to the function object. The 2 variables are independently referring to the same function.

The function explicitly overwrites whatever `scareMe` is pointing to. It does not affect `prank` in any way.

Look at this:

```
scareMe = function() {
    alert("Double boo!");
};
```

There is nothing magic about this, it will reassign the closest `scareMe` variable, which happens to be the global one. It does not do anything else.

Comment: thanks for the answer but in second call shouldn't prank be pointing to the latest value of scareMe ( by lexical scoping ) not the old value.

Comment: @niteshsharma that's what I tried to explain. You are misunderstanding, there is nothing that would assign anything to `prank` (you do not see `prank = something` so how can `prank` change?) thus it's not changed.

Comment: @niteshsharma also what you are implying is assign-by-reference which is not related to lexical scoping and is not supported by javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `scareMe();` depends on the execute order.

If you call `scareMe();` before `prank();`, then it will alert `Boo!` and assign a new function to `scareMe`, so the next time you call `scareMe();`, it will alert `Double boo!`.

In your case, it is the same, you call `prank();`, it will alert `Boo!` and assign a new function to `scareMe`, so after that, if you call `scareMe();`, it will alert `Double boo!`.