# JavaScript references confusion

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why self defining function reference keeps pointing to the old function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898651/why-self-defining-function-reference-keeps-pointing-to-the-old-function)

I am quite confused with javascript reference behavior. please take a look at this code it is very clear javscript in passing the reference not creating new memory location.

```
Human.prototype = Monkey.prototype;
Human.prototype.name = "human";
Human.prototype.work = "love";

Joker.prototype = Human.prototype;
Joker.prototype.name = "joker";
Joker.prototype.act = "awesome";

joker = new Joker ();
human = new Human ();
human.name = 'joker';
```

now look at this one it is pretty much clear javascript is creating 2 separate memory location for scareMe and prank

```
var scareMe = function () {
   alert("Boo!");
   scareMe = function () {
     alert("Double boo!");
  };
};

var prank = scareMe; 
prank(); // "Boo!"
prank(); // "Boo!"

scareMe(); // "Double boo!"
```

please help me to understand this behavior.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking about the first or second code block? What behavior do you not understand?

Comment: You asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898651/why-self-defining-function-reference-keeps-pointing-to-the-old-function/11899017#11899017 before, what is the not clear point?

Comment: take anyone as reference and explain why it is different than other one.

Comment: ok, I am sorry if I am not clear but for me the confusing part is why in first code block javscript define only one memory location so when i change a property of joker instance it chnages human.prototype property. 

while in second example prank and scare me both get different memory location so any change in prank doesn't affect scare me.

Comment: That's just how it is. Variables point to the function directly; `prank = scareMe` does not create a pointer to `scareMe`. Objects on the other hand are different - you can't compare objects and functions in this regard. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898651/why-self-defining-function-reference-keeps-pointing-to-the-old-function/11947635#11947635) to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

First block :

```
Monkey = function(){};

Human = function(){};
Human.prototype = new Monkey(); // This is how you have to inherit properties of Monkey
Human.prototype.name = "human";
Human.prototype.work = "love";

Joker= function(){};
Joker.prototype = new Human();  // This is how you have to inherit properties of Human
Joker.prototype.name = "joker";
Joker.prototype.act = "awesome";

joker = new Joker ();
human = new Human ();
alert(joker.name);  // shows joker
alert(human.name);   // shows human
```

Actually it is not recommended to create properties in prototype. (ref: http://css.dzone.com/articles/ecmascriptnext-classes)

```
Monkey = function(){
    this.name = "monkey";
    this.work = "jump";
};

Human = function(){
    this.name = "human";
    this.work = "love";
};
Human.prototype = new Monkey(); // This is how you have to inherit properties of Monkey

Joker = function(){
    this.name = "joker";
    this.work = "awesome";
};

Joker.prototype = new Human();  // This is how you have to inherit properties of Human

joker = new Joker ();
human = new Human ();
alert(joker.name);  // shows joker
alert(human.name);   // shows human
```

Second block :

```
var scareMe = function () {       // `scareMe` is a global variable 
   alert("Boo!");
   scareMe = function () {       //  value of global `scareMe` will be changed when original `scareMe` gets executed for the first time
     alert("Double boo!");
  };
};

var prank = scareMe; 
prank(); // "Boo!" - because `prank` is original scareMe. but this execution changes value of `scareMe` 
prank(); // "Boo!" - same happens

scareMe(); // "Double boo!" - `scareMe` is having new function. it shows "Double boo!"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, i think you were trying to use Object inheritance, for which your assignment of prototypes is not fitting,
as assigning a prototype to an existing prototype, will cause the left hand side prototype to reference the other one.
Then it's only a matter of where in the code you assign those prototype variables, i.e.:

```
Human.prototype = Monkey.prototype;
//Human.prototype.name = "human";  -- not here
Human.prototype.work = "love";

Joker.prototype = Human.prototype;
Joker.prototype.name = "joker";
Joker.prototype.act = "awesome";

Human.prototype.name = "human";  // but here

joker = new Joker ();
human = new Human ();
alert(human.name) // outputs "human"
```

But you should be using this instead for object inheritance:

```
Human.prototype = new Monkey();
```

In your second example, prank gets the original scareMe function assigned.
The scareMe function outputs "Boo!" and reassigns the scareMe functionvariable.
This means the outermost "var scareMe" now points to a different function (which returns "Double Boo!").
But since prank still points to the original function, it will always execute the original code (output "Boo!" and reassign scareMe).

```
// i.e.: reverse the call order:
scareMe(); // "Boo!"
prank(); // "Boo!"
prank(); // "Boo!"
```

the first call of "scareMe" reassigns scareMe, but prank still points to the original function.